# Google spreadsheet cell with link shows "just text" vs "=HYPERLINK("https://xxxx","text")"

Tags: google-sheets

I'm having links in google spreadsheet cells and it has got below 2 formats shown in **fx field**

```
=HYPERLINK("https://xxxx","text")
```

`just text` but clicking on this in the cell opens the link

didn't understand for same kind of behaviour why there are 2 formats used ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have assumed that all links are created with the `HYPERLINK()` function. This is not so - your `just text` link is an example of a link created from the main menu.

There are (at least) two ways to create a hyperlink.

- The `HYPERLINK()` function ([doc](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093313)).

  - When you select the cell, you can see the function and its parameters - you mentioned this in your question.
- Main menu "Insert, Insert link".

  - This method also accepts a URL and text/label. However, when you select the cell, you only see the text. Hovering over the cell will produce a popup dialog showing the url (which is clickable), and options to copy, edit or remove the link.

Comment: Didn't understand why G has to maintain 2 options to add links ? Thanks for detailed info anyways